# How can i make a server just localy?

Tags: apache, server

I have 2 pc and I want to access the projects from the second can I make a method so when I start the pc I have access to the files with an ip or something?

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you running? If you're running MacOS, you can just go to Sharing Center and enable Web Sharing or File Sharing. This makes your $HOME/Public folder available on your local network. Open a console. Run the following snippet to learn your IP address:

```
ping -nc1 `hostname`
```

Browse to http://YOUR.IP.ADDRESS/.

If you're running Debian GNU/Linux or Ubuntu Linux, open a console and run the following code to start a webserver and learn your IP address:

```
sudo apt-get install micro-httpd
hostname -i
```

Comment: If you don't know your IP address, tell us that. If you do know it, but typing it in results in just a hang or other suspicious (firewall) issues, detail exactly your results.